# Create suite of interdependent Lua files without affecting the global namespace

Tags: lua

**tl;dr**: What design pattern allows you to split Lua code over multiple files that need to share some information without affecting the global table?

#### Background

It is considered bad form to create a library in Lua where requiring the library affects the global namespace:

```lua
--> somelib.lua <--
SomeLib = { ... }

--> usercode.lua <--
require 'somelib'
print(SomeLib) -- global key created == bad
```

Instead, it is considered a best practice to create a library that uses local variables and then returns them for the user to assign as they see fit:

```lua
--> somelib.lua <--
local SomeLib = { ... }
return SomeLib

--> usercode.lua <--
local theLib = require 'somelib' -- consumers name lib as they wish == good
```

The above pattern works fine when using a single file. However, this becomes considerably harder when you have multiple files that reference each other.

#### Concrete Example

How can you rewrite the following suite of files so that the assertions all pass? Ideally the rewrites will leave the same files on disk and responsibilities for each file. (Rewriting by merging all code into a single file is effective, but not helpful ;)

```lua
--> test_usage.lua <--
require 'master'

assert(MASTER.Simple)
assert(MASTER.simple)
assert(MASTER.Shared)
assert(MASTER.Shared.go1)
assert(MASTER.Shared.go2)
assert(MASTER.Simple.ref1()==MASTER.Multi1)
assert(pcall(MASTER.Simple.ref2))
assert(_G.MASTER == nil)                   -- Does not currently pass
```

```lua
--> master.lua <--
MASTER = {}
require 'simple'
require 'multi'
require 'shared1'
require 'shared2'
require 'shared3'
require 'reference'

--> simple.lua <--
MASTER.Simple = {}
function MASTER:simple() end

--> multi.lua <--
MASTER.Multi1 = {}
MASTER.Multi2 = {}

--> shared1.lua <--
MASTER.Shared = {}

--> shared2.lua <--
function MASTER.Shared:go1() end

--> shared3.lua <--
function MASTER.Shared:go2() end

--> reference.lua <--
function MASTER.Simple:ref1() return MASTER.Multi1 end
function MASTER.Simple:ref2() MASTER:simple()      end
```

---

#### Failure: Setting the Environment

I thought to solve the problem by setting the environment to my master table with a self-reference. This does not work when calling functions like `require` however, as they change the environment back:

```lua
--> master.lua <--
foo = "original"
local MASTER = setmetatable({foo="captured"},{__index=_G})
MASTER.MASTER = MASTER
setfenv(1,MASTER)
require 'simple'

--> simple.lua <--
print(foo)         --> "original"
MASTER.Simple = {} --> attempt to index global 'MASTER' (a nil value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving master.lua two responsibilities:

1. It defines the common module table
2. It imports all of the submodules

Instead you should create a separate module for (1) and import it in all of the submodules:

```
--> common.lua <--
return {}

--> master.lua <--
require 'simple'
require 'multi'
require 'shared1'
require 'shared2'
require 'shared3'
require 'reference'
return require'common' -- return the common table

--> simple.lua <--
local MASTER = require'common' -- import the common table
MASTER.Simple = {}
function MASTER:simple() end
```

etc.

Finally, change the first line of `test_usage.lua` to use a local variable:

```
--> test_usage.lua <--
local MASTER = require'master'
...
```

The tests should now pass.

Comment: `Master.Simple = {}` references the *local* variable `MASTER`. This is initialized in the previous line to be the table returned by the module `common`. The `etc.` simply implies that the line `local MASTER = require'common'` should be added to the beginning of each of the remaining files.

Comment: That should have been `MASTER.Simple = {}`. Also, the code was tested before posting.

Comment: Forgive me; my comment was clearly wrong. I see now that your suggestion is actually quite simple and elegant, and works because `require` caches the common table. It sort of becomes the global variable, yet it cannot conflict with any other.

Comment: That's correct - and you may initialize any shared state in the table in `common.lua` without ever needing to resort to global variables.

Answer (score 3):

I have a systematic way to solve that problem. I have refactored your module in a Git repository to show you how it works: https://github.com/catwell/dont-touch-global-namespace/commit/34b390fa34931464c1dc6f32a26dc4b27d5ebd69

The idea is that you should have the sub-parts return a function that takes the main module as an argument.

If you cheat by opening the source files in *master.lua*, append a header and a footer and use `loadstring`, you can even use them unmodified (only *master.lua* has to be modified, but it is more complex). Personally, I prefer to keep it explicit, which is what I have done here. I don't like magic :)

EDIT: it is very close to Andrew Stark's first solution, except I patch the MASTER table directly in the sub-modules. The advantage is that you can define several things at once, like in your *simple.lua*, *multi.lua* and *reference.lua* files.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the problem by changing the master file to modify the environment in which all required code is run:

```lua
--> master.lua <--
local m = {}                        -- The actual master table
local env = getfenv(0)              -- The current environment
local sandbox = { MASTER=m }        -- Environment for all requires
setmetatable(sandbox,{__index=env}) -- ...also exposes read access to real env

setfenv(0,sandbox)                  -- Use the sandbox as the environment
-- require all files as before
setfenv(0,env)                      -- Restore the original environment

return m
```

The `sandbox` is an empty table that inherits values from `_G` but that also has a reference to the `MASTER` table, simulating a global from the perspective of later code. Using this sandbox as the environment causes all later requires to evaluate their "global" code in this context.

We save the real environment for later restoration, so that we don't mess with any later code that might want to actually set a global variable.

Comment: This answer works, but the use of setfenv was depricated in Lua 5.2. For that reason, I posted an alternate solution and voted this one up, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The question concerns:

1. Not polluting the global space when making modules.
2. Making modules in such a way that they might be split into multiple files, for maintenance reasons, among others.

My solution to the above problem lies in tweaking the "return as table" idiom in Lua such that instead of returning a table, you return a function that returns a table, when state needs to be passed between sub-modules.

This works well for sub-modules that are entirely dependent upon some root-module. If they *are* loaded independently, then they require the user to know that they need to *call* the module before they can use it. This is unlike every other module that has a collection of methods, ready to go from `local a = require('a')`.

At any rate, this works like so:

```
--callbacks.lua a -- sub-module
return function(self)
    local callbacks = {}
    callbacks.StartElement =  function(parser, elementName, attributes)
        local res = {}
            local stack = self.stack

    ---awesome stuff for about 150 lines...

    return callbacks
end
```

To use it, you can...

```
local make_callbacks = require'callbacks'
self.callbacks = make_callbacks(self)
```

Or, better yet, simply call the *return value* of *require* when assigning the callback table to the parent module, like so:

```
self.callbacks = require'trms.xml.callbacks'(self)
```

Most often, I try not to do this. If I'm passing state or self between submodules, I find that I'm often doing it wrong. My internal policy is that if I'm doing something that is highly-related to another file, I *might* be okay. More likely, I'm putting something in the wrong spot and there is a way to do it without passing anything between modules.

The reason that I don't like this is that which I pass by table has methods and properties unseen in the file that I am working within. I'm not free to refactor the internal implementation of one of my files, without horking the others. So, I humbly suggest that this idiom is a *yellow* flag, but probably not a red one. :)

While this solves the problem of state-sharing without globals, it doesn't really protect the user from the accidental omission of `local`. If I may speak to that implied question...

The first thing that I do is remove access to the global environment from my module. Remembering that it's only available as long as I don't
reset `_ENV`, reseting it is the first thing that I do. This is done by packing only what is needed into a new `_ENV` table.

```
_ENV = {print = print, 
    pairs = pairs, --etc
}
```

However, constantly re-typing all of the things that I need from lua into each file is a giant, error-prone pain. To avoid this, I make one file in my module's base directory and use it as the home for all of my modules' and sub-modules' common environments. I call it `_ENV.lua`.

Note: I cannot use "init.lua" or any other root-module for this purpose, because I need to be able to load it from the sub-modules, which are being loaded by
the root-module, which loads the sub-modules, which are...

My abbreviated `_ENV.lua` file looks something like the following:

```
--_ENV.lua
_ENV = {
    type = type,  pairs = pairs,  ipairs = ipairs,  next = next,  print =
    print,  require = require, io = io,  table = table,  string = string,        
    lxp = require"lxp", lfs = require"lfs",
    socket = require("socket"), lpeg = require'lpeg', --etc..
}
return _ENV
```

With this file, I now have a common base from which to work.
All of my other modules load this first, using the following command:

```
 _ENV = require'root_mod._ENV' --where root_mod is the base of my module.
```

This facility was critical for me, for two reasons. First, it keeps me
out of global space. If I see that I am missing something from the global environment `_G` (took me a surprisingly long time before I saw that I didn't have
tostring!), I can go back into my `_ENV.lua` file and add it. As
a required file, this only gets loaded one time, so having it applied
to all of my submodules is 0 calories.

Second, I find that it gives me everything that I really needed for using
the "return module as table" protocol, with only a few exceptions where "return a function that returns a table" is needed.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** *Don't* `return` the module, set `package.loaded[...] = your_module` as early as possible (can still be empty), then just `require` the module in submodules and it will be properly shared.

---

The clean way to do this is to explicitly register the module and not rely on `require` to implicitly register it at the end.  The documentation says:

> #### [`require (modname)`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require)
>
> Loads the given module. **The function starts by looking into the
>   `package.loaded` table to determine whether `modname` is already loaded.
>   If it is, then `require` returns the value stored at
>   `package.loaded[modname]`.** *[This gets you the caching behavior that
>   every file is run only once.]*  Otherwise, it tries to find a *loader* for
>   the module.  *[And one of the searchers is looking for Lua files to run,
>   which gets you the usual file loading behavior.]*
>
> […]
>
> Once a loader is found, `require` calls the loader with two arguments:
>   `modname` and an extra value dependent on how it got the loader. (If the
>   loader came from a file, this extra value is the file name.)  If the loader
>   returns any non-nil value *[e.g. your file `return`s the module table]*, 
>   `require` assigns the returned value to `package.loaded[modname]`.  If the
>   loader does not return a non-nil value and has not **assigned any value to
>   `package.loaded[modname]`**, then `require` assigns `true` to this entry.
>   **In any case, `require` returns the final value of
>   `package.loaded[modname]`**.
>
> <sub>(**emphasis**, *[comments]* added by me.)</sub>

With the `return mymodule` idiom, the caching behavior fails if you have a loop in your dependencies – the cache is updated too late.  (As a result, files may be loaded several times (you may even get endless loops!) and sharing will fail.)  But explicitly saying

```
local _M = { }           -- your module, however you define / name it
package.loaded[...] = _M -- recall: require calls loader( modname, something )
                 -- so `...` is `modname, something` which is shortened
                 -- to just `modname` because only one value is used
```

immediately updates the cache, so that other modules can already `require` your module before its main chunk `return`ed.  (Of course, at that time they can only actually use what's already been defined.  But that's not usually a problem.)

The `package.loaded[...] = mymodule` approach works in 5.1–5.3 (incl. LuaJIT).

---

For your example, you would adjust the start of `master.lua` to

```
1c1,2
< MASTER = {}
---
> local MASTER = {}
> package.loaded[...] = MASTER
```

and for all other files

```
0a1
> local MASTER = require "master"
```

and you're done.