# lua attempt to index global "StaticBody" (a boolean value)

Tags: lua, love2d

I tried to Experiment a bit with Objects in lua so I tried to make a StaticBody and a Collision and a Hitbox object but it spits out an error when I start the main in the line I create the staticbody: "main.lua:4 attempt to index global 'StaticBody' (a boolean value)"

https://pastebin.com/UFnEcYcT
here's the Code

```
--main.lua
 
StaticBody = require"StaticBody"
collision = require"collision"
 
player = StaticBody.StaticBody:new(300, 200, 40, 30, "RECT", 2000, 5000, 8.9, 900, 900, 5)
 
function love.load()
    playerimg = love.graphics.newImage("player.png")
    player:setSprite(playerimg, 1, 1, 0, 0)
end
 
function love.draw()
    player:draw()
end
 
function love.update(d)
 
    if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
        input = -1
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
        input = 1
    end
    if not love.keyboard.isDown("a") and not love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
        input = 0
    end
 
    player:update(d,input)
end
 
 
function love.keypressed( key, scancode, isrepeat)
    if key == "space" then
        player:jump(800)
    end
end
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--StaticBody.lua
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
StaticBody = {x = 0, y = 0, w = 1, h = 1, speedx = 0, speedy = 0, maxxspd = 1, maxyspd = 1, collosionmode = "RECT", sprite = nil, scalex = 1,
 scaley = 1, offsetx = 0, offsety = 0, acc = 1, decel = 1, grav = 1, velx = 0, colbox = nil, hitbox = nil, turningfriction = 2}
 
collision = require"collision"
 
function clamp(variable,vmin,vmax)
    if variable < vmin then
        variable = vmin
    end
    if variable > vmax then
        variable = vmax
    end
end
 
function StaticBody:new(x, y, w, h, colmode, acc, decel, grav, maxxspd, maxyspd, turningfriction)
    setmetatable({},StaticBody)
 
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.w = w
    self.h = h
    self.hitbox = collision.hitbox:new(x,y,w,h,false)
    self.colbox = collision.ColObjekt:new(colmode,self.hitbox)
    self.acc = acc
    self.decel = decel
    self.grav = grav
    self.maxxspd = maxxspd
    self.maxyspd = maxyspd
    self.speedx = 0
    self.speedy = 0
    self.turningfriction = turningfriction
    self.velx = 0
 
    return self
end
 
function StaticBody:setSprite(sprite, scalex, scaley, offsetx, offsety)
    self.sprite = sprite
    self.scalex = scalex
    self.scaley = scaley
    self.offsetx = offsetx
    self.offsety = offsety
end
 
function StaticBody:draw()
    love.graphics.draw(self.sprite,self.x,self,y,0,self.scalex,self.scaley,self.offsetx,self.offsety,0,0)
end
 
function StaticBody:update(d,input)
    local dir = 0
    if input == -dir then
        self.speedx = self.speedx / self.turningfriction
    end
    if input then
        dir = input
    end
    if not self.colbox:getOnGround() then
        self.speedy = self.speedy + self.grav * d
    end
 
    if input ~= 0 then
        self.speedx = self.speedx + self.acc * d
    else
        self.speedx = self.speedx - self.decel * d
    end
 
    clamp(self.speedx,0,self.maxxspd)
    clamp(self.speedy,0,self.maxyspd)
 
    self.velx = self.speedx * d * dir
    self.y = self.y + self.speedy * d 
    self.x = self.x + self.speedx * d * dir
end
 
function StaticBody:jump(jumpforce)
    self.speedy = -jumpforce
end
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--collision.lua
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
ColObjekts = {}
ColObjekt = {mode, x, y, w, h, collisionObjekts = ColObjekts}
--Constructer
function ColObjekt:new(mode,x,y,w,h,collisionObjekts)
    setmetatable({},ColObjekt)
 
    self.mode = mode
    self.collisionObjekts = collisionObjekts
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.w = w
    self.h = h
    ColObjekts.push(self)
 
    return self
end
 
--Constructer with Hitbbox
function ColObjekt:new(mode,Hb,collisionObjekts)
    setmetatable({},ColObjekt)
 
    self.mode = mode
    self.collisionObjekts = collisionObjekts
    self.x = Hb.x
    self.y = Hb.y
    self.w = Hb.w
    self.h = Hb.h 
end
 
function ColObjekt:setcolObjekts(colobs)
    self.collisionObjekts = colobs
end
 
function ColObjekt:getColliding()
    for key,i in pairs(self.collisionObjekts) do
        if getCollidingWith(self,i) then
            return true
    end
    return false
end
end
 
function ColObjekt:getCollidingWhich()
    for key,i in pairs(self.collisionObjekts) do
        if getCollidingWith(self,i) then
            return true, i
    end
    return false
end
end
 
function ColObjekt:getCollidingDir(Colob1,Colob2)
    if not getCollidingWith(Colob1,Colob2) then
        return false 
    elseif Colob1.y > Colob2.y then return "ONTOP"
    elseif Colob1.x < Colob2.x and Colob1.y > Colob2.y+Colob2.h then return "LEFT"
    elseif Colob1.x > Colob2.x and Colob1.y > Colob2.y+Colob2.h then return "RIGHT"
    else return "UNDER"
    end
end
 
function ColObjekt:getOnGround()
    if self:getCollidingDir(self,self:getCollidingWhich()) == "ONTOP" then
        return true
    else
        return false
end
 
function getCollidingWith(Colob1,Colob2)
    --if Colob1 == Rectangle
    if Colob1.mode == "RECT" then
        if Colob2.mode == "RECT" then
            ColRect_Rect(Colob1,Colob2)
        end
        if Colob2.mode == "CIRCLE" then 
            ColRect_Circle(Colob2,Colob1)
        end
    end
 
    --if Colob1 == Circle
    if Colob1.mode == "CIRCLE" then
        if Colob2.mode == "CIRCLE" then 
            ColCircle_Circle(Colob1,Colob2)
        end
        if Colob2.mode == "RECT" then 
            ColRect_Circle(Colob1,Colob2)
        end
    end
end
 
function ColRect_Edges(c,r)
    --OBEN
    if  c.x > r.x and c.x < r.x + r.w
    and c.y > r.y - c.h and c.y < r.y then return true
    --UNTEN
    elseif c.x > r.x and c.x < r.x + r.w
    and c.y > r.y + r.h - c.h and c.y < r.y + r.h then return true   
    --LINKS
    elseif  c.y > r.y and c.y < r.y + r.h
    and     c.x > r.x - c.w and c.x < r.x then return true
    --RECHTS
    elseif c.y > r.y and c.y < r.y + r.h
    and    c.x > r.x + r.w - c.w and c.x < r.x + r.w then return true 
    --WENN NICHTS ZUTRIFFT
    else return false end  
end
 
function ColRect_Corners(c,r)
    if math.sqrt((c.x - r.x * c.x - r.x) + (c.y - r.y *  c.y - r.y)) < c.w/2 then 
        return true
    elseif math.sqrt((c.x - (r.x + r.w) * c.x - (r.x + r.w)) + (c.y - r.y *  c.y - r.y)) < c.w/2 then 
        return true
    elseif math.sqrt((c.x - (r.x + r.w) * c.x - (r.x + r.w)) + (c.y - (r.y + r.h) *  c.y - (r.y + r.h))) < c.w/2 then 
        return true
    elseif math.sqrt((c.x - r.x * c.x - r.x) + (c.y - (r.y + r.h) *  c.y - (r.y + r.h))) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
 
function ColRect_Rect(r1,r2)
    if r1.x < r2.x + r2.w and r1.x > r2.x - r1.x and r1.y > r2.y - r1.h and r1.y < r2.y + r2.h then
        return true
    end
    return false
end
 
function ColCircle_Circle(c1,c2)
    local scndx = c1.x - c2.x
    local scndy = c1.y - c2.y
    if math.sqrt((scndx * scndx) + (scndy *  scndy)) < c1.w/2 + c2.w/2 then 
        return true
    end
    return false
end
 
function ColRect_Circle(c,r)
    if c.x > r.x and c.x < r.x + r.w
    and c.y > r.y and c.y < r.y + r.h then
        return true
    end
    if ColRect_Corners(c,r) then 
        return true
    end
    if ColRect_Edges(c,r) then
        return true
    end
    return false
end
 
 
 
Hitbox = {x,y,w,h,show = false}
function Hitbox:new(x,y,w,h,show)
    setmetatable({},Hitbox)
 
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.w = w
    self.h = h
    self.show = show
 
    return self
end
 
function Hitbox:update()
    if self.show then
    love.graphics.Rectangle("fill",self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h)
    end
end
 
function Hitbox:setVisible(b)
    self.show = b
end
 
end
```

Comment: I believe you have to `return` the value you want to export from a module.

Comment: Either replace `StaticBody = require"StaticBody"` with `require"StaticBody"` or add line `return StaticBody` at the end of the module.

Comment: @niclaswerther Can we wrap this one up then?

Answer (score 2):

When you `require` a module in Lua, the value that is handed to you is the one that is `return`ed at the very end of the module. In the absence of such a return statement, Lua seems to implicitly return a boolean (`true` or `false`) instead.

You need to `return StaticBody` at the end of `StaticBody.lua`. The same goes for every other module that your project interfaces with.

See [this](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) article for details.

---

As @nobody mentions in a comment, you can also decide what to export by assigning to the `package.loaded` table yourself.

```
package.loaded.StaticBody = StaticBody
```

Comment: `return`ing the module value is only one option. You can explicitly assign to [`package.loaded`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.loaded), and what ends up there is what actually matters. (`require` just assigns a `return`ed value for you.) For this situation, it will have the same effect, but (unlike `return M`) this would also work if you have loops in the dependencies (like `foo` requiring `foo.A` which requires `foo`). (It also keeps all module stuff in one place vs. creating the module at the top and `return`ing it at the end.)

Comment: The article I linked to mentions `package.loaded` but I suppose I could mention it here too. Not sure if I'd recommend it over the other alternative, but I'm not a Lua buff.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that this way is mentioned, because it's forgotten about all too often. The resulting "create module = _must_ use `require`" misconception in many people's heads makes them [come up with convoluted "workarounds"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14942472/805875) to solve dependency loops, and that's causing too much unnecessary pain.

Comment: That's fair. Thanks for bringing it up. I assume you noticed the edit?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I'd say creating cyclic dependencies is a bad idea in general (and the OP hasn't done that as far as I can tell), which is why the *canonical* method still stands as the main answer.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Whoops! I meant "_must_ use `return`" (and I can't edit the comment… -.-). Of course, `require` is the canonical way to load modules. Assigning to `package.loaded` is covered by the documentation of `require`, so I wouldn't call it a hack. (Expanding on that goes too far off-topic.)